# Add a WFS layer into an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I am having a lot of hard time trying to add a WFS layer from a Geoserver instance in my localhost. I am following the original example from OpenLayers website a-la-lettre just changing the URL value.
Here is the code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenLayers-v4.1.1/ol.css" type="text/css"> 
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="OpenLayers-v4.1.1/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <title>OpenLayers Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:Communes&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [30.158, -1.993],
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 12
        })
      });
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that my map is empty. I am only getting the ZoomIn/ZoomOut controls.
From googling the problem, I saw a mention of the cross-site-request issue which I resolved by adding the following code in the *Geoserver-root*/WEB_INF/web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, this didn't solve my problem.
Can anyone give me hints of what I am missing?

Comment: Dont you have any firebug errors???? Also check your geoserver log to identify the error if any.

Comment: if all else fails what does opening your url in a browser show you?

Comment: Opening the URL in the browser shows me the data in JSON.